# How can i populate fields in an html form on scrolling

Tags: javascript, forms, scroll, population

I have a form having arround 300 fields. I want to show the data on a button click. The data of the form is stored as an object (key - value pair). Currently am facing some delay on populating the complete 300 fields at a single run. Is there any way to populate the fields that displayed initially in the form and later on scrolling to the area populating the else as its show to the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you have 300 elements in a form, it's probably time to break that page up into sub-pages. :)

You don't need to worry about scroll position. What you want to do is NOT populate your form in a tight, render-blocking, CPU-bound loop.

You want to populate the form as fast as you can, and maintain page responsiveness.

Just put your code in a setTimeout(). Say your form has exactly 300 elements to populate (you can figure out how to deal with the dynamic size case):

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  setTimeout(20, function(i) {
   for (var j = i*10; j < 10; j++) {
      populateFormElement(j);
   }
  });
}
```

This will cause the browser to populate 10 form elements, and then yield so that the page can remain responsive. Tweak the timeout value as appropriate.

EDIT: yes, you could also do the scrolly thing with element.scrollTop, window.innerHeight, and a scroll event. But there will still be delays if a user jumps further down the page. Moreover, it's complex, and has edge cases. I think the answer above is what you want -- to eliminate the 'delay'.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, will try this and will let you know

Comment: I have tried the same and understood the logic, but it doesn't gives me the advantage i need

Comment: Can you describe the issue that you're seeing, and how you'd ideally like it to behave?